# ¿Cómo puedo referenciar un ListView en un fragment?

Tags: android-studio

Intento hacer un List view pero no se como referenciarlo porque lo quiero agregar en un fragmento. Mi aplicación se divide por fragmentos y mis datos están en una clase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el código de tu `Fragment`?, el código está en la carpeta res y el archivo se llama `fragment_servicios.axml`, primero debes definir un `ListView` ahi, asignarle un `id` y dicho `id` debes utilizarlo para buscar la referencia.

Answer (score 0):

Para un Fragment en el metodo `onCreateView` simplemente intenta

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_insumos, container, false);
    listaDatos = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listaDatos);
    //Cualquier otro codigo
    return view;
}
```

Es claro tambien que no debes implementar codigos despues del `return`